# How to optimize the join of two dataframes (by date-time)?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with the date and time of arrival and departure of subjects. I'd like to know how many subjects are present at each minute of a lapse time.

I first tried to achieve this goal with a loop, and then, based on what I have seen on this forum, using a SQL query. Both ways work but are extremely time-consumming.

```r
# dataframe with arrival and departure date of the subjetcs
individual <- data.frame(start=c("2018-01-01 13:22", "2018-01-01 14:00","2018-02-07 09:38"),
                         end=c("2018-01-01 15:43", "2018-01-01 14:05","2018-02-23 10:36"))
individual$start <- as.POSIXct(individual$start)
individual$end <- as.POSIXct(individual$end)

# dataframe containing every minute over a lapse time
moment <- data.frame(seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01"),as.POSIXct("2018-02-28"), by="1 min"))
colnames(moment) <- "dateTime"


# 1rst method : for every minute in the lapse time, I seek how many rows in "individual" contain this minute
moment[,"nbInd"]=0
for(k in 1:length(moment[,1])){
  print(k)
  moment$nbInd[[k]] <- nrow(individual[(which(moment$dateTime[k]>=individual$start & moment$dateTime[k]<=individual$end)),]  )
}
res <- as.data.frame(table(moment$dateTime)-1)


# 2nd method
dum1 <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM moment  LEFT JOIN individual ON dateTime >= start AND dateTime < end")
res <- as.data.frame(table(dum1$dateTime)-1)
```

In realty, my dataframe "individual" contains around 900.000 rows, and my dataframe "moment" is also longer. I could eventually change the dataframe "moment" to have a step every 10 minutes and not 1, but that would be a very bad solution to me. 
I am very new to SQL, but maybe a quicker SQL query would exist ? Or do you see any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: quickly: try `data.table` 

Comment: @MichaelChirico what would be the easiest way to do the equivalent of "select *" (as in this question) when doing a `[.data.table` join, i.e. select all columns from both tables? I've been wondering if there was some sort of setting/argument for this I've been missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not much experience in SQL, but since `data.table` provides SQL-like non-equi joining operations, here is a `data.table` solution using a non-equi join.

```
library(data.table)
#create data.tables out of the data sets
setDT(moment)
setDT(individual)
#update moment with column N, which is the result of rowcount (.N) of the 
#results of a non-equi join of each row of moment on individual 
#i.e.: N = how many rows in moment are between $start and $end of individual
moment[, N := individual[ moment, 
                          on = .(start <= dateTime, 
                                 end >= dateTime), 
                          .N, 
                          by=.EACHI]$N ]
```

will work...

900,000 rows should not be a big problemn for `data.table`.

Comment: It works very well, thank you. I just added ",allow.cartesian=TRUE" to avoid a message error.